# Chrome new tab autofocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extension and I am using the following:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Test extension",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Test extension.",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "cc.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**cc.html**

```
<style>body,html{padding:0;margin:0}</style>
<iframe src="theiframe.html" frameborder="0" height="200px" width="200px">
</iframe>
```

**theiframe.html**

```
<style>body,html{padding:0;margin:0}</style>
<form action="http://www.example.com/search">
    <input autofocus="autofocus" tabindex="1" type="text" />
    <input tabindex="2" value="search" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the user opens new tab the **autofocus** will be in the address bar. I want the users to be able to change that. Is there any code that will automatically autofocus the search input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it can't work using just an `iframe`. But you can make a sample page which will redirect to the page you want when a new tab is opened, so the `input` which has `autofocus` will be automatically focused.

Here is a way to do it:

**manifest.json**

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "r.html"
},
```

**r.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Loading...</title> <!-- user friendly -->
    <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://www.google.com"> <!-- in case javascript is disabled -->
    </noscript>
    <script src="s.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

**s.js**

```
window.location="https://www.google.com";
```

This is the best way to do it (and probably the only way).

Answer (score 4):

As Erik Kay (the director of Chrome engineering) pointed out in [this Chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243102#hc5), the intended behaviour is for the Omnibox to have focus by default and it is not possible to change this.

As such, the bug was marked as `WontFix`.

Comment: :) the report even quotes the docs like [I did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23746163/383793).

Answer (score 2):

A tip from the [API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override#tips):

> **Don't rely on the page having the keyboard focus.** 
>   The address bar always gets the focus first when the user creates a new tab.